# Merge point data columns Latitude and Longitude into one latlon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake, task

Here is my current rake task to import from CSV could I rewrite it to import and delete the two former columns / concatenate the data into one latlon column using space as a delimiter?

```
require 'csv'

desc "Import public library data from csv file"

task :import => [:environment] do
  namespace :import_incidents_csv do
    task :create_incidents => :environment do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "COPY PublicLibraryBranchLocations          (DistrictNumber, DistrictName, LibrarySystem, Type, Branch, Phone, Email, Website, PhysicalAddress, City, Province, PostalCode, Latitude, Longitude) FROM '/home/mgmacri/data/PublicLibraryBranchLocations.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COPY itself couldn't do that, but you could change the CSV before importing it.

One approach is COPY to a temporary table then use something like this to import:

```
INSERT INTO PublicLibraryBranchLocations(DistrictNumber, DistrictName, LibrarySystem, Type, Branch, Phone, Email, Website, PhysicalAddress, City, Province, PostalCode, LatLon) 
SELECT DistrictNumber, DistrictName, LibrarySystem, Type, Branch, Phone, Email, Website, PhysicalAddress, City, Province, PostalCode, Latitude ||' '|| Longitude
FROM TEMP_PublicLibraryBranchLocations;
```

As you can see, there is a concatenation at end `Latitude ||' '|| Longitude`.

Another approach is by creating a FOREIGN TABLE using [file_fdw](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html), so you can read the CSV file directly as a table (maybe called `PublicLibraryBranchLocations_FDW_CSV`) without importing that and importing the data from this table to `PublicLibraryBranchLocations` using something like:

```
INSERT INTO PublicLibraryBranchLocations(DistrictNumber, DistrictName, LibrarySystem, Type, Branch, Phone, Email, Website, PhysicalAddress, City, Province, PostalCode, LatLon) 
SELECT DistrictNumber, DistrictName, LibrarySystem, Type, Branch, Phone, Email, Website, PhysicalAddress, City, Province, PostalCode, Latitude ||' '|| Longitude
FROM PublicLibraryBranchLocations_FDW_CSV;
```

Comment: This is all making sense so far, I'm going to test today and may have some questions. Thanks!